# Search and return distinct rows with the count of their repitition

Tags: mysql, count, where-clause

I have created my SQL Fiddle on the following URL for testing and building my query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5415d/3

Consider the following structure of my table:

```
TABLE1
+-------------------------+
| Username  |  Event ID   |
+-------------------------+
| Jhon      |   ABC       |
| Nick      |   ABC       |
| Hen       |   ABC       |
| Jhon      |   DEF       |
| Jhon      |   ABC       |
+-------------------------+
```

The Query I am trying to write is that when user want to see the eventsID related to user `Jhon` then as you can see that there are various similar id against jhon in the above table and some are not so query should return something like the following output in Descending order as per `Count (Event_ID)`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| Username  |  Event ID   |  Count (Event_ID)   |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| Jhon      |   ABC       |    3                |
| Jhon      |   DEF       |    1                |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Kindly let me know how can I write such query.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select min(username) as username, 
       eventid, 
       count(eventid) as event_count
from table1
where username = 'Jhon'
group by eventid
order by event_count desc
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5415d/9)

Comment: In MySQL you can select a non-aggregated column while using a `group by`. But in most DB engines you need to use a aggregate function for all columns that are not grouped by. Since `username` is not grouped by I chose `min` as aggregate function.